# Загрузка аудиофайлов в базу данных приложения ruby on rails через PaperClip: Content Type Spoof

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пробовал через Paperclip выгружать аудиофайл, однако постоянно получал ошибку:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof
```

Весь гугл облазил, нигде ничего нет. Видимо, этот гем годится только для загрузки изображений, но никак не для того, чтобы с его помощью загружать аудиозаписи.

модель:

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :audiofile, AudiofileUploader

  has_attached_file :audiofile
  validates_attachment_content_type :audiofile, content_type: /\Aaudio\/.*\z/
end
```

контроллер:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_track, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tracks = Track.all
    json_response(@tracks)
  end

  def create
    @track = Track.create!(track_params)
    json_response(@track, :created)
  end

  def show
    json_response(@track)
  end

  def update
    @track.update(track_params)
    head :no_content
  end

  def destroy
    @track.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  private
    def track_params
      params.permit(:name, :description, :genre, :audiofile, :created_by)
    end

    def set_track
      @track = Track.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  :audiofile => "application/octet-stream"
}
```

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, чего вы хотели добиться в `paperclip.rb`, если `:content_type_mappings` мапает **расширения** файлов в их MIME-типы: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations Или у вас и впрямь файлы с названиями `*.audiofile`?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у гема PaperClip есть имеется защита для предотвращения загрузки файлов с содержимым, которое отличается от заявленного. По хорошему нужно в модели, к которой подключаете возможность загрузки, явно разрешить загрузку аудио-файлов при помощи метода `validates_attachment_content_type`

```
class AudioFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :audiofile
  validates_attachment_content_type :audiofile, content_type: /\Aaudio\/.*\z/
  ...
end
```

Ключ `content_type` позволяет задать регулярное выражение для допустимого MediaType-файла, список возможных медиа-типов можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2#audio). Регулярное выражение в примере позволит загружать произвольный аудио-файл, но если вам требуется определенный формат, его можно поправить под него.

Comment: Я вставил Ваш код, однако ничего не поменялось: я не могу загрузить mp3-файл на сервер.

Comment: @SemyonKotov пожалуйста дополните ваш вопрос примером модели, к которой подключен ParperClip, я не вижу вашего кода, поэтому атрибут :audio вставлен лишь для примера, его нужно заменить на ваш атрибут, которые проведен через миграцию и находится в базе данных.

Comment: Добавил весь код

Comment: @SemyonKotov После добавления validates_attachment_content_type сервер конечно был перезагружен? Если заменить на do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :audiofile ситуация меняется?

Comment: Да, конечно. Не раз пробовал перезапускать. Нет, код не заменял

Comment: А если вообще валидацию отключить? do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :audiofile?

Comment: Если отключить, происходит то же самое.

Comment: Content Type Spoof: Filename ggg.mp3 ( from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination. Все время одно и то же выдается. В доках нет ничего

Comment: Попробуйте в config/initializers/paperclip.rb вместо application/octet-stream указать audio/mpeg или вообще закомментировать содержимое config/initializers/paperclip.rb + do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :audiofile в модели.

Comment: Нет, абсолютно ничего не меняется.

Comment: Неужели совсем не существует способов загружать аудиофайлы в ruby on rails?

Comment: @SemyonKotov Я завтра попробую развернуть стенд с PaperClip и пощупать руками в Rails 5.x (я так понимаю дело с 5 версией имеете). В качестве альтернативы так же можно попробовать гем СarrierWave  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave . Вместе с PaperClip они вместе являются двумя наиболее популярными гемами по обслуживанию загружаемых файлов. Однако, популярность их настолько велика, что маловероятно что в PaperClip какой-то банальный косяк — попробую завтра живую систему развернуть. Пока можно попробовать СarrierWave — тоже очень хороший.

Comment: Знаете, я решил использовать гем Dragonfly. Загрузить файл получилось, осталось только получить url к нему.

Comment: А нет, он слишком уж непопулярный и ничего про это не найти

Comment: @SemyonKotov "слишком непопулярный" вовсе не означает, что документации нет. А она есть, и весьма подробная: http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/models#urls

Comment: В любом случае, я воспользовался carrierwave и все заработало. Прекрасная библиотека с замечательной документацией.